# $ajax is not working with ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am debugging my solution on localhost and this piece of code is not hitting the server

```
var cartInfo = $j("#ctl00_BaseContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_updateShoppingCart").html();
var dataString = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&date=' + date.val() + '&cart=' + cartInfo;

$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LightBoxContactSender.aspx",
    data: dataString,
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure there is no JS error before `$j.ajax` is executed.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console or firebug?

Comment: Thanks, I am now passing the info as JSON but my Request.Form collection is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing the `cartInfo` as an html, it should be url encoded before it is posted. I think this is wat causing this issue. Try this

```
var cartInfo = 
    $j("#ctl00_BaseContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_updateShoppingCart").html();
var dataString = 'name=' + name.val() 
            + '&email=' + email.val() 
            + '&phone=' + phone.val() 
            + '&date=' + date.val() 
            + '&cart=' + encodeURIComponent(cartInfo);

$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LightBoxContactSender.aspx",
    data: dataString,
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
```

As suggested by in other answer you can also pass data as a key/value pair object to `ajax` method, jQuery will take care the rest but you still have to encode the html content.

Answer (score 4):

the are 2 potential problems

1. the url
2. the data

`aspx` assumes webforms, the page life cycle, etc. when all you want is to send response and get a reply. instead try targeting either a

1. web service (asmx)
2. generic handler (ashx)
3. a static pagemethod think ajax server hanlders embedded within a page object

second is the data. instead of passing a string as the data try passing a json object

```
data = {
    name: "john",
    email: "john@email.com",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Url Doesnt call any method ?

```
  url: "LightBoxContactSender.aspx",
```

If yoy are trying to call a WebMethod inside aspx

```
  url :"LightBoxContactSender.aspx/callStaticMethod",
```

Try to form Data as

```
   dataString = "{'name=' + '"+name.val()+"'}"
```